# AccessibilityService onUnbind not always called when running on emulator

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm developing an accessibility service for Android. The problem is that, when running on the emulator (Android 4.0.5 API 15), **sometimes** onUnbind is not called when the service is switched off. When this happens, it is not possible to stop the service and I need to reinstall the apk or reboot the emulator.

When running this accessibility service on an actual device (Galaxy Nexus) it works fine. I have not been able to reproduce this problem.

Relevant service code is as follows:

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService {
    boolean mRunning= false;

    private void init() {
        if (mRunning) {
            // if execution reaches this point means that onUnbind was
            // not called the last time the service has been switched off                    
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Unsubscribe all accessibility events. Cannot be removed directly from
         * @xml/accessibilityservice, otherwise onUnbind and onDestroy // never
         * get called
         */
        setServiceInfo(new AccessibilityServiceInfo());

        // Initialization stuff

        mRunning= true;
    }

    private void cleanup() {
        if (!mRunning) return;

        // cleanup stuff

        mRunning= false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {

        init();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        cleanup();

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        cleanup();
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

- Am I missing something?
- I'm able to detect when this happens (see comments on init() ). Is there any way to force the service to stop?

**Additional details:**

- The service includes a native part and spawns two threads
- On the emulator it consumes the 100% of the CPU, on the Galaxy Nexus about the 35%
- After failing the first time, no matter how many times the service is switched on and off, onUnbind is never called again.